# attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded

Tags: docker

I am trying to use overlay network with `docker-compose up` (in swarm mode) because I need some other swarm to connect to that network as well.

I am getting this error:

> ERROR: for elk_elasticsearch_1  Cannot start service elasticsearch: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded
>
> ERROR: for elasticsearch  Cannot start service elasticsearch: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded
>
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Here's my docker-compose:

```
networks:
  elk-network:
    attachable: true
    driver: overlay
    name: elk-network
services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: 7.1.1
      context: /home/user/elk/elasticsearch
    environment:
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: password
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx256m -Xms256m
    networks:
      elk-network:
    ports:
    - published: 9200
      target: 9200
    - published: 9300
      target: 9300
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - /home/user/elk/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
    - /home/user/elk/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw
  kibana:
    build:
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: 7.1.1
      context: /home/user/elk/kibana
    depends_on:
    - elasticsearch
    networks:
      elk-network:
    ports:
    - published: 5601
      target: 5601
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - /home/user/elk/kibana/config/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro
version: '3.5'
```

The node Spec.Availability says active. I'm not finding any other information about what to do by googling the error.

The network called `elk-network` actually shows up in `docker network ls`

```
2l911valz0a8        elk-network              overlay             swarm
```

Edit: Another thing I've discovered from trying to debug is it works perfectly on my mac and on another server, but it doesn't work on the one server I need it to. Any way I can get more info about what's going on?

Comment: Not sure I've ever seen `null` added to a network element. What happens if you leave that out? i.e. just using `elk-network:`

Comment: it's not there in the file, that's a copy paste from `docker-compose config` which adds it for some reason. Also the problem only occurs after I adde network overlay and attachable, on network bridge it worked normally. It also works normally on my mac and another server I tested. No clue how to debug any more.

Comment: Did you init as swarm or join a swarm already? From: https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay ... `Before you can create an overlay network, you need to either initialize your Docker daemon as a swarm manager using docker swarm init or join it to an existing swarm using docker swarm join. Either of these creates the default ingress overlay network which is used by swarm services by default. You need to do this even if you never plan to use swarm services. Afterward, you can create additional user-defined overlay networks.`

Comment: yes, I did init swarm, I think it won't let you run an overlay network without, it forces you to init.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you also need to play with the subnet parameters, gateway, IP ranges, etc.

**Example:**

```
docker network create -d overlay \
  --subnet=192.168.0.0/16 \
  --subnet=192.170.0.0/16 \
  --gateway=192.168.0.100 \
  --gateway=192.170.0.100 \
  --ip-range=192.168.1.0/24 \
  --aux-address="my-router=192.168.1.5" --aux-address="my-switch=192.168.1.6" \
  --aux-address="my-printer=192.170.1.5" --aux-address="my-nas=192.170.1.6" \
  elk-network
```

Comment: can you explain a bit why these could be the problem, I don't know much about servers. I will try your solution when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by uninstalling docker from snap and reinstalling using `apt` using these commands;

```
sudo snap remove docker
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install docker.io
sudo reboot
```

After that, I was able to successfully create my network.

I do the `dpkg` and `update` command to make sure my system is clean for re-install.